# How to transfer a powershell list variable to terraform by using Azure Devops?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have a list which is filled with addressprefixes like **192.168.1.0/24**

```
$listOfSubnetsToBeCreated = @() 
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=availableSubnetList]$listOfSubnetsToBeCreated"
```

created in a powershell and transferred to azure devops pipeline variable that i have already defined in Azure Devops.
[image]
I am using this variable which is set on the run with

```
terraform apply -var="availableSubnetList=$(availableSubnetList)"
```

in my Terraform task to create a subnet. Here below is the tf script:

```
variable "availableSubnetList" {
  type = list(string)
  default = [""]
}
resource "azurerm_subnet" "Subnet-lab" {
    count = var.project_subnet_number
    name = join("-", ["${var.LabRGName}","subnet", "${count.index + 1}"])
    resource_group_name = var.AdminRGName
    virtual_network_name = var.lab_vnet
    address_prefix = var.availableSubnetList[count.index]
}
```

When i executed the pipeline, i am having the following error on **terraform apply** task:

```
2020-05-25T14:39:52.5509261Z [0m  on <value for var.availableSubnetList> line 1:
2020-05-25T14:39:52.5510090Z   (source code not available)
2020-05-25T14:39:52.5510378Z 
2020-05-25T14:39:52.5510814Z This character is not used within the language.
2020-05-25T14:39:52.5511149Z [0m[0m
2020-05-25T14:39:52.5511412Z [31m
2020-05-25T14:39:52.5512135Z [1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1mInvalid expression[0m
2020-05-25T14:39:52.5512438Z 
2020-05-25T14:39:52.5512833Z [0m  on <value for var.availableSubnetList> line 1:
2020-05-25T14:39:52.5513301Z   (source code not available)
2020-05-25T14:39:52.5513582Z 
2020-05-25T14:39:52.5513977Z Expected the start of an expression, but found an invalid expression token.
2020-05-25T14:39:52.5514566Z [0m[0m
```

Afaik, the variables in Azure Devops are strings. Do you have any idea on how to transfer a powershell list correctly to terraform by using Azure Devops?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Output a comma-separated string of subnets from the PowerShell script:

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=availableSubnetList]$($listOfSubnetsToBeCreated -join ',')"
```

Then split it into a list again when invoking terraform:

```
terraform apply -var='availableSubnetList=${split(",", $(availableSubnetList))}'
```

Or change the way you resolve each subnet in terraform:

```
address_prefix = split(",", var.availableSubnetList)[count.index]
```

Comment: i have applied it and got this error: 
2020-05-25T12:21:07.2672860Z [1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1mInvalid reference[0m
2020-05-25T12:21:07.2674089Z 
2020-05-25T12:21:07.2675081Z [0m  on network.tf line 8, in resource "azurerm_subnet" "Subnet-lab":
2020-05-25T12:21:07.2676095Z    8:     address_prefix = [4mavailableSubnetList[0m[count.index]
2020-05-25T12:21:07.2676984Z [0m
2020-05-25T12:21:07.2700114Z A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute
2020-05-25T12:21:07.2701181Z access, specifying the resource name.

Comment: here $(availableSubnetList) seems empty at the logs:  the terraform.exe plan -var=LabRGName=rg-deniztest3-87719dccbe -var=project_subnet_number=3 "-var=availableSubnetList=${split(,, )}"   Although i enter -var="availableSubnetList=${split(",", $(availableSubnetList))}"

Comment: i noticed that i made an error in tf script: address_prefix = availableSubnetList[count.index] . It should be var.availableSubnetList[count.index]

Comment: @MoonHorse I'm not 100% sure the `${split()}` expression works when passed at the command line, you might need to do it in the task itself

Comment: i guess you are right, after i have corrected my small error, i got this log : terraform apply -auto-approve  "-var=availableSubnetList=${split(,, 10.0.2.0/24,10.0.3.0/24,10.0.4.0/24)}" It seems split() doesn't function

Comment: do you mean the powershell script or in the azure devops task?

Comment: i have splitted it inside terraform script and it worked. address_prefix = split(",", var.availableSubnetList)[count.index]

Comment: @MoonHorse That's great (sorry I couldn't be of more help with tf, not my strongsuit). I've updated my answer to reflect your solution as well :)