# Passing Terraform output to Powershell task in Azure Devosps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, terraform

In Azure DevOps we have the follwing `YAML` pipeline which is applying Terraform configuration from a `CmdLine` task.
The Output task should return the ObjectId of a `Data Factory` after it is deployed by `Terraform`.
I would like to use that ObjectId and pass it to the next `Azure Powershell Task` as a parameter so I can add that Id as member to an AzureADGroup.
How can I use the output from the step called 'Terraform output' in the next `Powershell` Task?

[image]

```
  - task: CmdLine@2
    displayName: Terraform Apply
    enabled: False
    inputs:
      script: terraform apply -auto-approve -input=false tfplan
      workingDirectory: infrastructure/tf_scripts/dev
  - task: CmdLine@2
    displayName: Terraform output
    enabled: False
    inputs:
      script: |
        terraform output adf_objectid
      workingDirectory: infrastructure/tf_scripts/dev

  - task: AzurePowerShell@4
    displayName: 'Azure PowerShell script: InlineScript'
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: 'a6cb1cd3-8d5e-4db6-8af5-bcb66492d5cc'
      ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
      Inline: |
                $spn=(terraform output adf_objectid)
                Connect-AzureAD -AadAccessToken $aadToken -AccountId $context.Account.Id -TenantId $context.tenant.id -MsAccessToken $graphToken
                Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx -RefObjectId $spn
      workingDirectory: wd/scripts/dev
      azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Passing Terraform output to Powershell task in Azure Devosps

You could try to use the the [Logging Command](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) to set the `adf_objectid` as an azure devops pipeline variable:

```
echo ##vso[task.setvariable variable=spn]$(terraform output adf_objectid)
```

Check the [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62000885/how-to-transfer-a-powershell-list-variable-to-terraform-by-using-azure-devops) for some details.